# Upload profil picture to every member

Tags: plugins

I have a lot of members in my Intranet website and I need to assign a personal picture to each one of them. I have a folder that contains all the pictures with the name of every member.

How can I do that? Is there a plugin that I can install ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a plugin may be you answer
https://www.flippercode.com/product/wp-user-avatar/ (Pro Paid Version)
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/ (free Version)

This will still take some manual addition of attaching photo to user but it means you can bypass the gravatar route if you dont want to get everyone to signup to https://en.gravatar.com/ which many user may not want to do.

I have no affiliation with these plugins but have used the free version for a similar task to yours

Comment: Yeah I see, thank you! I installed https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/. Can you please tell me where I should exactly modify the code?